# Take integer from input with string and integer

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.8

I want to figure out how to take the integer from a input when there is both a integer and string.

For example, if I input "hello 3", is there a way I can separate the "3" to another variable aside from the "hello"?

Comment: You could do **split** on input and the check **type** to do necessary conversion.

Answer (score 0):

Would this work for you:

```
myInput=input() # Get Input
myString,myIntStr=myInput.split(" ") # Split in to list based on where the spaces are
myInt=int(myIntStr) # Convert to int
```